How can I bulk include files in Visual Studio matching a particular pattern?
I am working on a large existing codebase in a variety of languages, including MATLAB and Python, which uses meson for its build.
I have created a Visual Studio makefile project for this using New Project From Existing Code, in order to be able to set up build and debug rules. This has worked fine, except...
...I didn't include *.py and *.m among my filters of files to include when creating the project. This means searches don't find matches in any Python or MATLAB files.
I know I can add the files individually (or even in a folder) by saying "Show all files", selecting them in the Solution Explorer, right-clicking, and selecting "Include in Project". The problem is there are a LARGE number of these files scattered over a large number of directories, so working through the whole project to do this will take a long time.
Is there any way to retrospectively add (say) all *.py files in the source tree in one operation?

In the end I checked out a clean version of the project (so that there were no generated files in the directory tree), and created a new Visual Studio project using Create From Existing Code, setting the file filter to ..
I then did a file compare of the old .vcxproj against the new one and copied across the various NMake settings from the old one to the new (which was easy because the new one had none, so they were just a complete new block).
Having saved the updates to the new project, I overwrote the old file with the new one.
Note: trying to copy the added files from the new project to the old one left me with an unloadable project, because the files in the projects were in different orders so I ended up with a whole load of duplicate files.
